# american date format to EU

Tags: sql, date, format

Do we have any function in SQL, to convert US date format into EU?
I was trying by the easiest way and sum substrings from EU format - it worked well till I didn't not get US format.

Example:

1/2/2015 convert into 2015-01-02 00:00:00 (smalldatetime)

I'm working on MSSM 2008

BR

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date, like this:

```
select convert(datetime,GETDATE(), 103)
```

`103` is British/French, there is a list [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp), `110` is US. Just change it to the format you want :)